# How can I do to show up a confirmation modal from bootstrap validation js file?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, jquery-validate

I'm having a hard time here. Let me explain.

I have a form and a js validation. If validation is ok a confirmation modal appears to submit (or not) some info to the database:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
    <!-- BEGIN VALIDATION STATES-->
    <div class="portlet box green">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption"><i class="icon-reorder"></i>Formulario de Carga</div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body form">

            <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
            <form action="{site_url()}admin/testupdate" id="form_sample_2" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">

                <div class="alert alert-error hide">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert"></button>
                    Existen errores en el formulario. Por favor verifique.
                </div>

                <!-- modal -->
                <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                        <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Cargar Usuario</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Desea dar de alta al nuevo usuario?</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
                        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="confirm btn green" id="btnYes">Confirmar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
                <!-- end modal -->

                <h3 class="form-section">Datos Personales</h3>
                <!-- row 1 -->
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6 ">
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">Celular<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" class="m-wrap span8" name="cellphone" value="{$okInfo['cellphone']}" required> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn green">Validate</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
                <!-- END FORM-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END VALIDATION STATES-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have two js files, one for validation and to display the modal if information is ok.. and the other with this code, in order to submit form content to a function in admin.php:

```
$('#btnYes').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#form_sample_2').submit();
});
```

When clicking confirm button from modal, modal disappears but it doesn't redirect to the submit function.

I'm using Codeigniter,  Bootstrap v3.0.0, jQuery 1.10.1, jquery validation plugin, Smarty Template engine.

Checked on chrome and firefox browsers.

I think that the problem might be the submit handler from validation file. This is the snippet:

```
var form2 = $('#form_sample_2');
var error2 = $('.alert-error', form2);
var success2 = $('#myModal', form2);

form2.validate({
  errorElement: 'span', 
  errorClass: 'help-inline', 
  focusInvalid: false, 
  ignore: "",
  rules: {
    cellphone: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 9,
      maxlength: 11,
      digits: true
    }
  },
  //some code
  submitHandler: function (form) {
    success2.modal('show');
    error2.hide();
  }
});
```

So is submitHandler function the one that is not letting me submit the form because after checking validation and after modal appears, if clicking in modal's submit button then it does AGAIN the validation and post never gets to the function in the controller.

So my question now is how can I do to avoid this second validation and to submit the form? I'm burned right now

Comment: _Everything_ concerning the modal needs to be _inside_ the `submitHandler`, not just the line that opens the modal.  Ideally, the modal would have a custom callback function that is fired when the button is clicked.  Then `form.submit()` would go inside that.

Comment: Also, to ignore nothing, it's `ignore: []`, not `ignore: ""`.

Comment: @Sparky I did build a function inside submit handler where it opens the modal and send the submit order, but it's not working. If you give me 5 minutes I'll edit my post with that. About the ignore thing, I didn't touch it, just came like that from the original plugin. Don't really know what is for either. I'm really new at this.

Comment: Came from what plugin?  Those are options that _YOU_ configure and the Validate plugin doesn't come with any of that filled out for you.

Comment: @Sparky I didn't put the " ". For real.

Comment: Where did that code above come from if you didn't write it??  It contains your specifics… `cellphone`, `form_sample_2`, etc… how did all that get there if not from you?  Code gnomes?

Comment: @Sparky Of course I customized it with my needs, that was not what I was saying. I just said that I didn't put the "" in the ignore line... The plugin is from Metronic template I'm using. It has html and js files to customize.

Comment: Ok, then.  Change the `""` to `[]` and [read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) so you understand what you're doing.  You might not even need to set the `ignore` option at all.  Leaving the `ignore` option out means the plugin will ignore all invisible fields.  Setting it to nothing, `""` or `[]`, means that it will validate all hidden fields (ignore nothing).

Comment: @Sparky yes, thank you. I'm just learning, trying, reading and practising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, if you leave out the `type`, the `button` will be `type="submit"`, and since it's already inside your `form`, it will act like another `submit` button again triggering validation.  Make it a `type="button"` and you won't need the `preventDefault()`...

```
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="confirm btn green" id="btnYes">Confirmar</button>
```

Everything needs to go inside the `submitHandler` if you want the submit handler to control it.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    success2.modal('show');
    error2.hide();
    $('#btnYes').on('click', function(){
        form.submit();
    });   
}
```

---

Otherwise, since `#btnYes` is already a `submit` button, your original `submitHandler` might work fine if you simply got rid of the `click` handler.

Comment: thank you very much. I thought I have tried this... but as I said my brain was burned. Now it works fine!